# 404 error comes up when I go to wp-admin after first installation

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

I just installed wordpress for the first time. When I go to mywebsite.com/wp-admin a 404 website error comes up. I went through the routine of changing the plugins and themes names although I never entered my wordpress dashboard anyway. Domains by Godaddy hosting by Hostgator. I changed the DNS to match the hostgator DNS. Uninstall and reinstall wordpress, nothing happened. What do I do?

Comment: "I never entered my wordpress dashboard anyway" - how did you set up the site without ever using the dashboard? Did you do all the setup using Hostgator tools then, not the wp-admin dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues seem likely:

1. Your DNS changes haven't propagated yet.  It takes awhile for the DNS change to spread across the internet.  Give it 1-2 hours and try again.  [*Hostgator recommends pointing your name servers to them.*]
2. If the issue remains, then check how your domain was entered into the quick installer.  It's possible that an extra `/` is causing the whole thing to fail.

If neither of these is the culprit, then I'd suggest you contact their support team at https://helpchat.hostgator.com